# How to require tether with webpack?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, amd, laravel-elixir

I have a webpack application I'm using with laravel elixir.  In this application I have a `bootstrap.js` file for initializing all of my libraries.  Here it is:

```
window._ = require('lodash');

/**
 * We'll load jQuery and the Bootstrap jQuery plugin which provides support
 * for JavaScript based Bootstrap features such as modals and tabs. This
 * code may be modified to fit the specific needs of your application.
 */

window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');// $ui = require("jquery-ui");
/**
 * import twitter bootstrap js library
 */
require('bootstrap-sass');
/**
 * import jquery ui
 */
require('jquery-ui-bundle');

/**
 * import jquery datatables
 */
require('datatables.net');

/**
 * import select2
 */
require('select2'); // globally assign select2 fn to $ element

/**
 * import d3
 */
require('d3');

/**
 dropdowns
 */
require('tether');
require('tether-drop');
```

The only issue is, when I go to build this, I get `Error: Can't resolve 'tether-drop'`.  How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: I have removed [tag:elixir], since it’s a tag to mark question related to the programming language.

Comment: @mudasobwa, it's an important tag because it means that config files traditionally used in web pack cannot be used

Comment: Oh, I see what your saying, let me change it.

Answer (score -2):

To use tether, you'll need to make it available on window.

```
global.Tether = require('tether');
```

Now, you can use it with another libraries, for examples, with bootstrap@4. Don't use import.

```
require('bootstrap');
```